# Average color of texture in Unreal 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So I'm getting a image of the current scene with a scene capture 2d and can use it with a rendertarget.
Now, is it possible to get the average color of this texture using blueprints only (or *very* basic C++)?

If it isn't directly possible I thought about blurring the texture heavily and just reading the color of the center pixel. Would that be doable?

I need the color for further stuff in a RGB format is possible.

The HUD:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdXLg.png

The material: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcKt4.png

The result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkURl.png

The material currently has the base color white for testing, as you notice the color of the HUD is still black though.

The MaterialExpressionTextureSampleParameter2D_6 is somehow the color of the first pixel of the texture. When I draw this on the HUD via Emissive Color (since Base Color doesn't work), it gets dimmed by black heavily.

What am I doing wrong here and how do I get the average color?

Comment: Can you get a pixel data of the texture into C++ array?

Comment: My C++ is very basic and I never looked under the hood of unreal.

Comment: You may want to try asking the question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ as well. There may be some people more familiar with Unreal Engine.

Comment: Another place to search for Unreal Engine related questions would be the answerhub on https://answers.unrealengine.com/.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Windows, you can attempt to use GetPixel (this is in the Windows.h library) to get the RGB value for a single pixel.

If you are using Linux, you can attempt to use XGetPixel (for X11) to get the same RGB value for a single pixel.

In the event you want to find the average color of pixel over some area (let's assume the area you want to cover is a square), you can have two for() loops, and a way to store the sum of the average color.  You would increment the x and y values in the for loop and keep track of the sum of the colors of the pixels.  At the end you would divide this sum by the number of pixels covered to get the average.